# javascript find method always returning last data set instead of matching id

Tags: arrays, vuejs3

I have two arrays where skedDatas array references sitePocs array's contactId. getContactInfo function's find method is always returning last sitePoc's (contactId 000002) object. I want is the sitePocs' object that matches the clicked data row's contactId. Where am I going wrong?

Github repo: https://github.com/EnergeticPixels/catalog

```
const skedDatas = [
  {
    classId: "00001",
    startDate: "07/10/2024",
    stopDate: "07/26/2024",
    location: "McAlester, OK",
    classNumb: "003",
    status: "Scheduled",
    contact: "Available",
    contactId: "000001"
  }
];
const sitePocs = [
  {
    contactId: '000001',
    pocTitle: 'For Registration Availability for this course on Mars',
    pocName: 'Galatic Desk',
    pocEmail: 'space-rangers-help@mars.glob',
    pocPhone1: '68-38-918-420-8707',
    pocPhone2: '',
    pocdsnPhone: '',
    altpocName: '',
    altpocEmail: '',
    altpocPhone1: '',
    altpocPhone2: '',
    altpocdsnPhone: ''
  },
  {
    contactId: '000002',
    pocTitle: 'craziness',
    pocName: 'venus operator',
    pocEmail: 'space-rangers-help@venus.mil',
    pocPhone1: '68-39-918-420-8707',
    pocPhone2: '',
    pocdsnPhone: '',
    altpocName: '',
    altpocEmail: '',
    altpocPhone1: '',
    altpocPhone2: '',
    altpocdsnPhone: ''
  }
];

const getContactInfo = (contactId) => {
  const contact = sitePocs.find((contact) => contact.contactId === contactId);
  return contact;
};
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?  The answer could be as simple as the parameter `contactId`, however you're sending it (you haven't shown), is always equal to `'000002'`, so it's returning the correct object.  That is to say, the error could be with how you're calling your method, not the method itself.  You might need to show more code

Comment: @yoduh you are onto something. When I consoled the contact return, the function is returning the right contact information. My problem appeared to be with Vue3's displayed information in my modal.

Comment: @yoduh I figured this part out.  The solution is ugly and will need to be refactored, but it works. getrowid function inside /src/pages/courses/ammo04.vue does return a filtered array like i want.   Thank you for the help.